# How can I get the Jetpack Image plugin to open links in a new window?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

The Jetpack image widget does not offer a target option for links. Is there a way to open all Jetpack image widget links in a new window without hacking the plugin? Like through a hook or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no hook available](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack/tags/2.1.2/modules/widgets/image-widget.php) in the plugin.

One solution is to simply copy this Jetpack Widget and add the target option.

Another is through jQuery, in the file `/theme/functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jetpack_widget_wpse_88067' );

function jetpack_widget_wpse_88067() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'jetpack-hack', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/jethack.js", 
        array( 'jquery'), // dependencies
        false, // version
        true // in footer
    );
}
```

And in the file `/theme/js/jethack.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $('.jetpack-image-container a').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add this to your `home.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  jQuery('.widget_image a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
</script>
```